# has_many through association does not save relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller

I have two models joined with a has_many through association:

Here are the tables:

```
  create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "mission"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "organizations_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
  end
```

Here are the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :organizations_users
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organizations_users

end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations_users
  has_many :users, :through => :organizations_users
  has_many :categories, as: :categorizable

end

class OrganizationsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

When I create a new organization via my form it creates adequately. However the relationship does not get saved when submitted via my form for some reason.

If I do something like this for example:

```
o = Organization.last
o.users
```

I get an empty query set:

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "organizations_users" ON "users"."id" = "organizations_users"."user_id" WHERE "organizations_users"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@organization) do |f| %>
  <% if @organization.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@organization.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this organization from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @organization.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control", autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class:"form-control", autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :mission %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :mission, class:"form-control", autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_organization, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /organizations
  # GET /organizations.json
  def index
    @organizations = Organization.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end

  # GET /organizations/1
  # GET /organizations/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /organizations/new
  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end

  # GET /organizations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /organizations
  # POST /organizations.json
  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @organization.save
        format.html { redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @organization }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /organizations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /organizations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @organization.update(organization_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @organization }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /organizations/1
  # DELETE /organizations/1.json
  def destroy
    @organization.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to organizations_url, notice: 'Organization was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_organization
      @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def organization_params
      params.require(:organization).permit!
    end
end
```

The weird part is that I created some seed data using Faker gem and the organization created that way seems to return a user when I do that same query via my rails console. So the wiring is correct but there must be a problem in my form or params in some way?

This is how I succesfully created a organization with a user associated to it via seed data:

```
for n in 1..10 do
  user = User.create!(
    first_name: Faker::Name.first_name, 
    last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
    email: Faker::Internet.email, 
    password: "password",
    employer: Faker::University.name,
    title: Faker::Name.title,
    short_bio: Faker::Lorem.paragraph)
  user.organizations.create!(
    name: Faker::Company.name, 
    description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph, 
    mission: Faker::Lorem.sentence)
end
```

Why is this happening? Relationship only doesn't work via form Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: maybe this could help: what about the `autosave: true` option? Without this option, you must save explicitly the object every time you update a relation.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't creating the relation in your controller's `create` method.  You currently have:

```
@organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
```

You should create like how you are creating it in your seed file:

```
@user = #find your user here
@organization = @user.organizations.new(organization_params)
```

This should create your organization and relation.

Comment: This is also not working it is still giving me an empty collection when I call .users on a newly created instance of an organization

Comment: Was your user record saved into the database?

Comment: I posted below my own answer of how I got it to work. It seems kind of hackey but it works....

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Is this in a test?

Comment: I edited my answer with controller code. No it is not in a test. This is only way to get it to work. I am not sure whyI have to do this but it doesnt work uneless I do this. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply want to create the join table manually. It's not the best way, but since you are stuck, maybe it will help you at least get the wheels rolling.

```
@organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
OrganizationsUser.create(
  user_id: current_user.id, organization_id: @organization.id
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. @organization does not have user_id column.... Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm... Looks like it's just built differently that I would thought. I took a look at the schema. To you, what is an `organizations_user`? Is it a different thing than a user, or is it just that some users are `organization_user`? You would not need a different table for this, just a column on both `organization` and `user`. see my updated answer.

Comment: Right, but why do you need a through? Is there a reason that you don't want to use use `has_many`? and `belongs_to`?

Comment: because 1 user can be part of may organizations and one organization can have many users...

Comment: any user can create an organization via the form, but is not necessarily the only one part of the organization. Others can join the organization at any later time.

Comment: Ok lol well that makes sense :-) Then yeah, ignore that other comment.

Comment: Any idea why this is not working? I've spent a full day on it and cant fix it. Seems like it should be simple thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89843/discussion-between-aaron-coding-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
u = current_user
o = u.organizations.build(name:'blah')
u.save
o.save
```

Have to save both objects to save relation for some reason. Not sure why.

something like this in controller:

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @organization = @user.organizations.build(organization_params)  

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save && @organization.save
```

Comment: missing `:autosave => true` ?